# my browser is showing the code of javascript instead of running the code ive written in it

Tags: java, html

Here's the code I've written to validate the login :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="javascript/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>JSP Page</title>
   </head>
   <body> 
   <% String username=request.getParameter("username"); 
   String password=request.getParameter("password"); 
   if((username.equals("root") && password.equals("Root@123"))) 
   {    
        session.setAttribute("username",username); 
        response.sendRedirect("admin.html"); 
    } 
    else if((username.equals("school") && password.equals("school@123"))) 
    {   
        session.setAttribute("username",username); 
        response.sendRedirect("school.jsp"); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");
    }
        %> </body>
</html>
```

but instead of executing its showing the code inside `<% - - - -   %>`.
somebody please help me out with this.
and sometimes does run and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is (probably one of Microsoft's abominations), but you're not running it as JavaScript.

Comment: Stupid question... Is your extension `.jsp`?

Comment: i just tried that,including my code between <script> and </script> it neither works that way,

Comment: @DavidThomas That wouldn't help.   He's not using javascript but rather java.  Using `<script>` wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @Second Rikudo : would it work if i run it in ubuntu for that matter?

Comment: @Evan: ah, I thought it looked a little wrong, bit I assumed they were just custom methods.

Comment: Is it running in a server environment?

Comment: @wobbles : so should i try .java extension for my file?

Comment: How are you running it? Have you setup a server like Tomcat?

Comment: @evan.stoddard : yes in server environment.

Comment: @surajk. well now that you clarified it is JSP, sounds like htaccess or server extension settings are getting in the way

Comment: @surajk. No the `.java` extension won't help at all

Comment: @fgb : yes tomcat 7.0

Comment: @surajk. yes, i posted my thoughts in the previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

The code is correct as far as it goes, and assuming your Java EE container is set up to treat the file as a JSP, it should be doing so, but one thing does jump out:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="javascript/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

You're setting the Content-Type of the response to `javascript/html` (which is, as far as I'm aware, a completely unknown MIME type). This *might* be preventing your Java EE container from attempting to treat it as a JSP, although it would surprise me a bit. The tag should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

That's speculation, but as the `meta` tag is definitely wrong, I'd fix it.

If that doesn't correct the issue, then you need to look at the setup of your Java EE container (Tomcat, JBoss, whatever you're using), as it's not treating the file as a JSP.

Comment: i tried using <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset=UTF-8"> but it was not working,so i tried   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="javascript/html"; charset=UTF-8">which is there in the post

Comment: @surajk.: Okay. (Just to emphasize: Java and JavaScript are completely different languages.) So fundamentally it's an issue with your Tomcat setup. For whatever reason, it's not treating the file like a JSP. That's your starting point for debugging what's going on.

Comment: will try and work with that in mind, thank you

Answer (score -1):

That code is not javascript, it is java. It looks like you're trying to use [Java Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) Pages (JSP), which generates HTML by running java code on your webserver which is then sent to the browser. Javascript is a completely different language which is usually run in the browser itself.

In order to make your code run rather than just be displayed in the page you need to set up a webserver that will execute the java code and serve the page.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Doorknob Why isn't an answer?  Just curious.  I need to learn a bit more about jsp.

Comment: Your first revision was more of a comment, as it didn't include the actual answer here (the second paragraph). (the answer is still quite lacking, and basically boils down to "make a webserver. Good luck!")

Comment: @Adam Harwood : thank you for the input. i had mistaken .jsp as java script, any suggestions wwhat i need to alter in the code to make it execute?